# Receive SharePoint list guid in xml

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I need to receive a SharePoint list guid for a custom application for my xslt. I checked both the xml of the SharePoint list as well as the xml generated through the RSS Feed of a SP List. The list guid does not seem to be included in any of them. Is there a way to get the list guid to be used in xslt?

I can only use the xml generated by the SharePoint for the list.

Comment: As there has not been any answers, I think this is not possible in case someone else is trying to achieve the same thing.